# Which tense to use here?

Tags: tense, would-rather

> I would rather you mended your ways or **be** ready to face the music.

Is the use of **be** above correct? Or should I replace it with **got** to maintain parallelism?

**be ready**, incidentally, shows which tense?

Comment: You sentence is not properly formed around the conjunction **or**.  When you say you would *rather* someone do something, you say you would rather they do it **than X**.  So your sentence would better written *I would rather you mend your ways **than** face face the music.*  This means you would prefer someone do X instead of experience Y.  If you want to use **or** you would say something like, *I suggest you mend your ways **or** be ready to face the music.*

Comment: @EllieK: Thank you! One more thing I needed to ask: Does *would rather* take the past form of the verb after it or the present form or any one of these? COLLINS, for example, gives *I would rather Lionel **took** it on.*